# Animate a sound Bar using vanilla js

Tags: javascript

I want soundbar effects i.e

1. I want the corresponding divs(bars) to increase/decrease height indefinetely like in the code snippet below. I want to acheive the same effect in Vanilla JS.
2. I want them to change height randomly i.e 5 bars will change height in 5 random ways.

The Element.animate() method is not doing the job and I am not allowed to use any external libraries or API's as well. I am unsure of using the CSS animate method.

The code written below is in jQuery. I am unable to decipher the same solution in Vanilla JS.

```js
function fluctuate(bar) {
  var amplitude = Math.random() * 42;
  console.log(amplitude);
  var height = amplitude * 4;
  //Animate the equalizer bar repeatedly

  bar.animate({
    height: height
  }, 1000, function() {
    fluctuate($(this));
  });
}

$(".bar").each(function(i) {
  fluctuate($(this));
  console.log($(this));
});
```

```css
.inline-block-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
}

.bar-wrapper {
  background-color: black;
  height: 160px;
  width: 135px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.bar {
  /*     background-color: green; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.bar-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 10rem;
  border: 15px solid black;
}

timers {
  display: flex;
}

.start {
  display: inline;
  background-color: green;
  margin-right: 50px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.stop {
  display: inline;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="bar-container">
    <div class="inline-block-wrapper">
      <div class="bar-wrapper">
        <div class="bar" style="background-color:#754ab7"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inline-block-wrapper">
      <div class="bar-wrapper">
        <div class="bar" style="background-color:#c640a5"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inline-block-wrapper">
      <div class="bar-wrapper">
        <div class="bar" style="background-color:#f05386"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inline-block-wrapper">
      <div class="bar-wrapper">
        <div class="bar" style="background-color:#f58169"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inline-block-wrapper">
      <div class="bar-wrapper">
        <div class="bar" style="background-color:#f9c059"></div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="timers">
    <button class="start" onClick=f luctuate()> Start</button>
    <button class="stop" onClick=s topSequence()> Stop</button>
```

Comment: Hey Shorya can you add more details as to what is that you want to achieve specifically and what is not being done right now ? Update the same in the question itself.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur Yes, I changed the question outlining the things I want to achieve. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You can use javascript `classList.add()` to add a class that has a certain CSS animation. You can use CSS Animation keyframes to create a kind of soundbar effect. If you want truly random animation you can use javascript `requestAnimationFrame` to adjust the height of your sound bar every frame. Just some tips! Read the documentation on MDN or W3Schools and try some things out :)

Answer (score 2):

Took a whole lot of CSS but I worked out a solution to something close to what I wanted.

```js
  var clicks = 0

          function fluctuate(){
                clicks+=1
                if(clicks>1){

                    stopFluctuation()
                }else{

                    document.querySelector('.div-stop').classList.toggle('animate-bars')
                    var bar = document.getElementsByClassName('div-bar')
                
                }
                
            
                
          }

          function stopFluctuation() {
            let count = 1;

            let bars = document.getElementsByClassName('div-bar');
            for(bar of bars) {
              bar.classList.toggle('paused-bars');
                             }
             
              }
```

```css
    .container {
                     border: 20px solid black;
                     background-color: black;
               }
 .button-container {
     display: flex;
               }
 .start {
     display: inline;
     background-color: green;
     margin-right: 50px;
     padding: 10px 10px;
     color: white;
     border: none;
     width: 100px;
     height: 35px;
     justify-content: center;
}
 .stop {
     display: inline;
     background-color: red;
     margin-left: 50px;
     padding: 10px 10px;
     color: white;
     border: none;
     width: 100px;
     height: 35px;
     justify-content: center;
}
 .div-stop {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     width: 550px;
     height: 150px;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .div-stop div {
     flex: 10 auto;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
}
 .animate-bars div {
     animation: animate-bar 500ms linear infinite alternate;
     transform-origin: bottom;


}
 .animate-bars div:first-child {
     margin-left: 0;
}
 .animate-bars div:last-child {
     margin-right: 0;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(1) {

     animation-duration: 2200ms;
     animation-delay: 9ms;
     position: relative;
     top:22%;

}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(2) {
     animation-duration: 1500ms;
     animation-delay: 0ms;
     position: relative;
     top: 33%;

}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(3) {
     animation-duration: 1789ms;
     animation-delay: 5ms;
     position: relative;
     
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(4) {
     animation-duration: 2786ms;
     animation-delay: 7ms;
     position: relative;
     top: 10%;
}
 .animate-bars div:nth-child(5) {
     animation-duration: 1659ms;
     animation-delay: 8ms;
     position: relative;
     top: 27%;
}
 
 @keyframes animate-bar {
     0% {
         transform: scaleY(0);
    }
     100% {
         transform: scaleY(100%);
         
    }
}
 body {
     height: 100vh;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: space-around;
}
 body::after {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     right: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 1px;
}
 .paused-bars {
     -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
     animation-play-state: paused !important;
}
```

```html
 <div class = "container">
            <div class="div-stop">
                    <div style="background-color:#754ab7" class="div-bar"></div>
                    <div style="background-color:#c640a5" class="div-bar"></div>
                    <div style="background-color:#f05386" class="div-bar"></div>
                    <div style="background-color:#f58169" class="div-bar"></div>
                    <div style="background-color:#f9c059" class="div-bar"></div>
               

            </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "button-container">
        <button id="start" class= "start" onClick="fluctuate()">Start</button>
        <button id="stop" class = "stop" onClick="stopFluctuation()">Stop</button>
    </div>
```